# Replace Default Wordpress Pages With Custom

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I installed WAMP on my Windows machine and then installed Wordpress.  We had a 3rd party develop a Wordpress site to use for this install, but anytime we launch localhost it takes us to the default Wordpress page.

From the .zip file received with the custom Wordpress site, what must I do to have the "Custom" site load instead of the "default" word press site?

It is not a simple copy of the custom and paste over the default as that changed nothing.

Comment: If I understood correctly you copied theme files into theme directory but nothing changed. Is that correct? Than you need to go to appearance->themes and activate the new theme that you have uploaded.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze - I copied everything (admin, content, includes, as well as the wp-*.php files.  How would I go to appearance and themes to activate it?  I am accessing locally u sing localhost/wordpress

Comment: Read about cloning wordpress website here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152076/how-do-i-clone-a-wordpress-site/37155943#37155943

Comment: @NickSurmanidze - that must be the issue then.  I was not delivered a database file!